# How to make responsive grid with first item in 2 columns?

Tags: html, css, grid

Consider this snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
      grid-column-gap: 10px;
      grid-row-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #aaaaaa;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .item {
      padding: 40px;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm on my way to learn the css&html basics and I'm trying to achieve the next effect:

- I'd like the first item on the grid to live in 2 "columns". This item should be a box containing both text, links and some nice border (obviously the text shouldn't go out out of margins)
- The whole grid should become responsive... so when you make the page smaller the number of columns will be reduced but never will be smaller than 2 columns, that way you'll be able to see the 1st item (which contains the whole description)

How would you code this type of layout?

Comment: Refer this, might be helpful https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will clarifie you some `grid` behaviors. 
More about grid basics

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout

`grid-area` (i used in this example)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

`grid-auto-rows` and `minmax();`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 time by 1fr (equal share of a grid)*/
      grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto); /* minmax(100px, auto) tracks the row content height and set valu (from, to) */
      grid-column-gap: 10px;
      grid-row-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #aaaaaa;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .container .item {
      background: #fff;
      font-size: 0; /* removing white blank line under an image*/
    }
    .container .item:nth-child(1) {
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
      /* first horizontal gap / first vertical gap / second horisontal gap / third vertical gap */
    }
    
    /* here ve have to cover our text so we can set font-size back to normal*/
    .container .item .text-cover {
      padding: 40px;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px; /* back font-size back from 0 */
    }
    
    /* we have to set max-width: 100%; to an img so it will not tear the parent */
    .container .item img {
      /*max-width: 100%;*/
      width: 100%; /* if we want image to be more thet its's max-width */
      height: auto;
      font-size: 0;
    }    

    /*act differently after screen width less then 575px*/
    @media (max-width:575px) {
      .container {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      }         
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="text-cover">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure <a href="#">dolor</a> in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="text-cover">
        Removed image from here for you to see, how minmax(100px, auto) works
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is really good... I've tested it out and I'm trying to understand why the items will go out of scope though. Please take a look to what I mean here [https://jsfiddle.net/zcawqo9t/](https://jsfiddle.net/zcawqo9t/) ... Maybe it's just me not knowing how to use properly your snippet though, I'd like to clairfy this one first before validating... +1 in the meantime.

Comment: Edited the answer. Now i considered all your requests. Added `grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);` with an explanation and link to a manual, and `img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}` so that the images do not break patent

Comment: Thank you very much, your question has already become more than good enough to be validated. One last question though... if you wanted to expand the images to fill the full cell, how would you do it?

Comment: `img {width: 100%; height: auto;}`, change `max-width` to `width`, this will expand image width more then it's natural. Although i added `font-size: 0;` to `.container > div` to remove the white blank line under images, and covered text in `<p>`(you can use any other tag), to set `font-size` back. Updated an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has become a really nice answer. Btw, isn't the `.item` selector unused, why did you add it?

Comment: You now, I simply forgot) Rewrited an answer a little, using class instead of plain tags. Using specific classes is better so as not to touch the excess elements. Rewrite a `.item` a little. This is not a strict manual, it's just a guide on howto deal with grid element. You can edit anything inside the way you like.

Comment: Well, definitely your answer has helped to get the basics down while creating my first website at [https://bpl.expert/](https://bpl.expert/) ... Although I'm facing a problem where the size of the images will be too big when the page is at full screen. Not sure how I'd could keep them at a smaller size like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/x5bteff3fijroh9/chrome_2020-05-24_01-41-31.png) , maybe you've got any advice? Not sure if this is already offtopic though hehe ;)

Comment: Add to `.cs16 { max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;}`. Or you can create another question with more details and send a link on it here.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Never mind, guys from #css at freenode have been helping me out and I think the design it's already getting close to my ideal vision. Thanks to advice here nevertheless... And you're right, next doubts I'll just open new question instead abusing this one which has already been addressed more than good enough, ty anyway. ;)